# Find payment date and user who payed for VIM Invoice

Tags: abap

In which table can I find the user who paid a VIM invoice and on what date?

Tables I've looked at are:

- BSEG
- BKPF
- BSAK
- RBKP

Comment: did you check: http://www.tcodesearch.com/sap-tables/search?q=vendor+invoice+management. These are normally all of the tables related to vim. RBKP sounds promising to me (haven't used this before so only taking a guess here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try tcode `/OPT/VIM_ANALYTICS`, there you can filter payed invoices and view needed invoice in corresponding tcode through forward navigation

[image]

Also, there is a table `/OPT/VIM_1LOG` where all actions of VIM invoice workflow are recorded.